# how do i stop the tkinter window being not interactable while a "computation heavy" function is running

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-multiprocessing

i have a tkinter window that does has some widgeds that the user can interact with and when a function that takes a little bit of time to run the whole window cant be interacted with.and i want to change that

i heard you can solve this problem by implementing multiprocessing to the function but i dont really understand how to implement it.

my code is something like this :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


def functionthattakessometime():

    while True:
         print("haa")

root=tk.Tk()

b=Button(root,text="print haha",command=functionthattakessometime)

a=Button(root,text="do nothing")

b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You cant press the "do nothing" window after you pressed the "print haha" button and i want to change that 
so you can press the "do nothing" button even after you pressed the "print haha" button.

Comment: run `functionthattakessometime` in `thread`. In some situations you can use `after(time, function_name)` instead of `while` 
 - ie. `def functionthattakessometime(): print("haa") ; root.after(100, functionthattakessometime)`. Or you can try `root.update()` inside `while` loop.

Comment: The `threading` library is what you are looking for. It is what I use for all my function that are cpu/time consuming so it does not block the main thread tkinter is in.

Comment: thank you the root.update was the one i used and it worked

Comment: You do not need `update()` and most of the time you should not be using `update`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `threading` library is what you want here.

Here is a simple example of how it would work with your code.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading


root = tk.Tk()
allow_print = True


def function_that_takes_sometime():
    while allow_print:
        print("haha")


def start_thread():
    global allow_print
    allow_print = True
    thread = threading.Thread(target=function_that_takes_sometime)
    thread.start()


def stop_thread():
    global allow_print
    allow_print = False


tk.Button(root, text="print haha", command=start_thread).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Stop print", command=stop_thread).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

That said I would change a few things.

First I would remove `from tkinter import *` as you should never import tkinter twice and it is better to just use `import tkinter as tk` because this prevents us from overwriting any methods on accident.

Second I would build this in a class so we can avoid global variables.

Here is an OOP version:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.allow_print = True
        tk.Button(self, text="print haha", command=self.start_thread).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Stop print", command=self.stop_thread).pack()

    def function_that_takes_sometime(self):
        while self.allow_print:
            print("haha")

    def start_thread(self):
        self.allow_print = True
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.function_that_takes_sometime)
        thread.start()

    def stop_thread(self):
        self.allow_print = False


Main().mainloop()
```

And to simplify this further because often threading is overkill we can use the `after()` method to manage the loop and not affect the mainloop.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.allow_print = True
        tk.Button(self, text="print haha", command=self.function_that_takes_sometime).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Stop print", command=self.stop_print).pack()

    def function_that_takes_sometime(self):
        if self.allow_print:
            print("haha")
            self.after(1000, self.function_that_takes_sometime)

    def stop_print(self):
        self.allow_print = False


Main().mainloop()
```

Comment: Good job simplifying this @Mike_SMT